# similar method in flex as destroy() in jsp?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Is there anything same in flex 3 as destroy() method in jsp?
  After clicking logout button i want to destroy the initialization of a page and reinitialize it 
  after i login again?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "page" but in Flex the garbage collecting is automatic, you don't need to call it explicitly, you just need to be sure that all references to objects are removed and set it to null.
You can of course implement you own logic for disposable elements in your application and do the cleanup there (remove all event listeners and other references prior to removing the object).